# Node.js mysql query response delay

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node.js mysql driver. But when the server under high load, i guess mysql is doing queue for queries. How can I prevent this? I want to do query instantly.

How can I resolve this? My queries are laggy.

My code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'ip',
  user     : 'db',
  password : 'pass'
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
connection.query('USE db');
connection.query({ sql:"select token,COUNT(token) as sayim from tokens where username=? or anon=?", timeout: 10000},[data,data],function(err,info) {
        if (info[0].sayim != 0) {
            callback(info[0].token);
        }else{
            callback("0");
        }
    });
```

Ps: The server is not returning any error for this. But when I do a query, server is responding after approximately 10 seconds. If server is not under the high load it is responding instantly.

Comment: what's your mysql configuration related to this problem? i.e. how many concurrent connections are allowed, what kind of load balancing is it prioritizing, etc?

Comment: I have allowed to 5000 concurrent connection. But I don't think mysql server is not related with this problem. Because my cpu load values is good and i am trying to run same query in phpmyadmin and server is responsing in 0.350ms . I think i have problem with node.js mysql driver.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PoolConnection](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections) instead.

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'ip',
  user     : 'db',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'db'
});
```

Another thing that comes to mind: In your example, you use asynchronous functions one after the other which should cause you some troubles as well.

Comment: What should be the connectionlimit ?

Comment: It mainly depends on your need for concurrent connections usually the default limit (10) is enough. If it's not, double it until you find the accurate value. Before editing this limit, I would make sure the slowness really comes from the number of concurrent connection and not from my code or my query (which may not be optimized enough and may take too much time)